# Is incest father-daughter incest permissible? Leviticus doesn't seem to prohibit this occurrence

Tags: law, moses, leviticus

I have seen the other question that has been asked concerning this matter, which is similar to my own(this) question. But I will still submit this question because I wish to be given rather **straight-forward, but copious answers.** As far as I can tell, father-daughter incest is possibly permitted. Am I wrong?